# Java socket client can't receive data from Node Server

Tags: java, node.js, sockets

i'm new in nodejs, i want create a socket server by nodejs.

and i write some simple code:

`nodejs`:

```
var sockets = [];
net.createServer(function (client) {
    sockets.push(client);
    client.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        client.write("you say:" + data); 
        setInterval(function(){
            client.write("Hell from server"); 
        }, 100);        
    });

    client.on('end', function () {
        sockets.splice(sockets.indexOf(client), 1);
    })

}).listen(PORT, HOST);
```

`java`:

```
Socket client;
BufferedReader buf;
...
boolean flag = true;
while (flag) {
    String echo = buf.readLine();
    System.out.println(null == echo || "".equals(echo) ? "-null-" : echo);
    if (null != echo && echo.contains("bye")) {
        flag = false;
    }
}
```

i think both the code are simplest, but when the client post data to server, the client only receive one message `you say: xxx`, the interval write maybe write to a "buffer" because when the client post data again, the client receive data like `Hell from serverHell from serverHell from serverHell from serverHell from serveryou say:xxx`. why is it so?

the same result when i try to catch user scanner on node server:

```
var readline = require('readline');
var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

rl.on('line', function (line) {
    for (var i in sockets) {
        if (sockets[i] && sockets[i].writable) {
            sockets[i].write(line);
        }
    }
```

the client can't receive the data, too.

how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading lines but you aren't writing lines. You need to add a line terminator to each sent message.

Comment: can you give me some suggest?

Comment: Add os.EOL () or append "\r\n" once you are done with write